# How do I know if a vehicle has stopped moving using sensors inside my android phone?

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors

Suppose i am traveling in a vehicle and i want to know if it is moving or not using the sensors in my android phone. is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

insted of sensors by using location manager & gps you can get it. Check it [here](http://insted%20of%20sensors%20by%20using%20location%20manager%20you%20can%20get%20it.%20developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)

if you really want to get the changes by using [sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html) you can go for  [Accelerometer](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-accelerometer-on-android--mobile-22125)